# How can I call execute on a AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android

I have a chunk of code that should get a specific value from a specific website. Apparently I need to execute it inside AsyncTask, but I don't really know anything about it. Could someone help me how to do this the "right" way?
How can I execute this AsyncTask code block that I've written?

Heres what I have currently:

```java
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String value = "presetvalue";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            class NamespaceResolver implements NamespaceContext {
                private Document document;

                public NamespaceResolver(Document doc) {
                    document = doc;
                }

                public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                    if (prefix.equals("")) {
                        return document.lookupNamespaceURI(null);
                    } else {
                        return document.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
                    }
                }

                public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
                    return document.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
                }

                public Iterator<String> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
                    return null;
                }
            }


            try {
                String url = "http://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs/fin?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&storedquery_id=fmi::observations::mareograph::timevaluepair&fmisid=134223&";

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                }
                String xml = sb.toString();

                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                Document document = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

                XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

                xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceResolver(document));

                String time = xpath.evaluate("//wml2:MeasurementTimeseries[@gml:id='obs-obs-1-1-WATLEV']/wml2:point[last()]//wml2:time", document);
                value = xpath.evaluate("//wml2:MeasurementTimeseries[@gml:id='obs-obs-1-1-WATLEV']/wml2:point[last()]//wml2:value", document);
                System.out.format("time = %s; value = %s\n", time, value);
                return value;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("EXCEPTIONFAIL", e.toString());
                return "FAIL: " + e.toString();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {

            MerenpintaWidget.eeee = feed;


        }
    }
```

This is basically the only part that I need to execute inside AsyncTask:

```java
try {
                String url = "http://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs/fin?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&storedquery_id=fmi::observations::mareograph::timevaluepair&fmisid=134223&";

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                }
                String xml = sb.toString();

                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                Document document = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

                XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

                xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceResolver(document));

                String time = xpath.evaluate("//wml2:MeasurementTimeseries[@gml:id='obs-obs-1-1-WATLEV']/wml2:point[last()]//wml2:time", document);
                value = xpath.evaluate("//wml2:MeasurementTimeseries[@gml:id='obs-obs-1-1-WATLEV']/wml2:point[last()]//wml2:value", document);
                System.out.format("time = %s; value = %s\n", time, value);
                return value;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("EXCEPTIONFAIL", e.toString());
                return "FAIL: " + e.toString();
            }
```

If this code is correctly written, can someone tell me how to call it? I don't really have any idea how to solve this, and I'm mostly just rambling now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to put url you have to use in your `doInBackground()` method . if you want to run your asyncTask class

```
String url = "http://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs/fin?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&storedquery_id=fmi::observations::mareograph::timevaluepair&fmisid=134223&";
public BackgroundTask  myTask = new BackgroundTask();
myTask.execute(url)
```

and in your `doInBackground()`

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(urls[0]).openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            }
            String xml = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Actually, this seems to give me a "Cannot resolve symbol 'execute'" and "Unknown class: 'url'" errors in `myTask.execute(url)`